# Is PHP's hash_file streaming internally?

Tags: php

I notice my machine's memory usage goes way up when I call `hash_file` on a large file (5GB). The operation completes successfully, but I'm wondering whether the internal implementation of `hash_file` streams the file contents into the hash algorithm or if it tries to load the entire file contents into memory first. Does anyone know?

Comment: Hashing can't be done sequentially. Each character changes the final hash completely. You could gzip the file first, but you would need to do that every time to compare hashes.

Comment: @Anthony: Absolutely untrue. The vast majority of hash functions in use today are calculated incrementally; they just operate on a blockwise basis, and use a finalization step, that makes it impossible to append data to a "completed" hash. They are entirely sequential internally, though.

Comment: Is that true for small data hashing as well, like sha256 on a 10 character password?

Comment: @Anthony Yes. Hashing operations are inherently streaming. There is no need to load the whole file into virtual memory in order to compute a hash; the algorithm maintains some amount of internal state and can be finalized at any time when the stream ends. You can hash any number of bytes >= 0 in exactly the same way, with some allowances for padding at the end of the stream. I'm really just asking whether PHP is being smart about this or not, because the documentation doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No one answered this correctly yet so I'm answering my own question. After a little test it turns out that `hash_file` *does* operate on the file as a stream instead of using something silly internally like `file_get_contents`. Tested by using an environment with a lower `php_memory_limit` value than the size of the file being hashed. (Should have done that in the first place, sorry for the noise.)

Comment: You had +5GB of memory allocated to php? If your concerned with performance you should tune your dev environment down anyway to get a better "in the wild" sense of performance.

Comment: No. I just verified that it was less than 5GB, which proves that it doesn't load the whole file. The memory blowup I experienced was not related to the `hash_file` call.

Comment: Well don't leave us in suspense! What was the root cause?

Comment: Was from another process entirely :)

Answer (score 4):

It maps the entire contents into virtual memory. The entire contents must be in physical memory for the hash operation to be performed, but not all at the same time. As always, the machine's physical memory contains portions of what is mapped into virtual memory, managed by the OS to make the most efficient use of physical memory.

If you think about it, it is basically unavoidable that all of the file's contents pass through physical memory at some point in order for the hash to be computed. Every byte of the file must be processed by the CPU to produce the hash and thus must be read if not already in memory. And if there's sufficient physical memory, you probably want it to stay there because a common pattern is to read the same file again after you've hashed it.

If you hash a file that's larger than physical memory, then some data will have to be discarded as new data is read in. The OS manages this by adjusting which pages of virtual memory are actually resident in physical memory. Pages that contain clean copies of data still available in the filesystem can be trivially discarded from physical memory and the physical memory used to hold newly-read information.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this answer. First, hash algorithms always operate on a stream. There is no need to keep more pages in virtual memory than the chunk currently being streamed to the algorithm. "And if there's sufficient physical memory, you probably want it to stay there because a common pattern is to read the same file again after you've hashed it." Pages from disk will be left in a physical memory LRU cache, but it would be totally silly for the whole file to be read into virtual memory to compute the checksum. After some reading, it turns out it does stream internally.

Comment: @zjm555 Nothing you said disagrees with anything in my answer. I never said there's a *need* to keep the data in physical memory, only that if sufficient physical memory is available, it makes sense to do so. (Because the data might be used against soon. And you can always throw it away later. There's no rush to throw information that might be useful away when keeping it around has zero cost.)

Comment: "If you hash a file that's larger than physical memory, then some data will have to be discarded as new data is read in." That makes it sound like the whole file is in memory at once. In practice, when streaming a hash you'll read in some fixed-sized chunk at a time from the file (typically on the order of KB, maybe MB) and that's all the memory you'll ever need. You would overwrite that fixed-size buffer with each read from the stream. The implementation of disk block caching by the disk controller or the OS is completely irrelevant to the question of the the implementation of `hash_file`.

Comment: @zjm555 Again, you're not disagreeing with me. The issue is not what memory you **need** but what memory will, in practice, actually be used. If there is sufficient physical memory, then most of the data *will* be in memory at once. However, you are incorrect about one thing -- the issue is not disk block caching but virtual page caching. Disk block caching basically doesn't exist any more -- modern OSes have a unified page cache. Yes, it real cases it uses lots of memory. Yes, it could work just as well with much less.